# Как получить стек потока, когда приходит сигнал SEGMENTATION FAULT?

Tags: c, unix, c++, linux

В многопоточной программе какой-то поток выполняет недопустимую операцию и ядро присылает сигнал **SEGMENTATION FAULT**. Я хочу посмотреть стек этого потока на момент выполнения недопустимой операции.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это можно сделать.
Я подозреваю, в обработчике сигнала можно что-то сделать, но вот что?

В принципе можно получить идентификатор потока при помощи функции **pthread_self()** и каким-нить образом достать стек этого потка...

Comment: core dump, а на него натравить gdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А какие у вас ограничения? Вы не можете воспользоваться gdb?

что-то типа

```
$ulimit -c unlimited
$./your_prog
$gdb -c core ./your_prog
gdb> bt
```

или вообще посмотреть прямо в gdb где все падает?

Answer (score 2):

После запуска gdb набираем :

```
 gdb> thread apply all bt full
```

Получаем стек выполнения для каждого запущенного потока плюс указание на то, в какой функции все завалилось.